# Mysql - Query Date Specific

Tags: mysql, date

I need some help of you!

I've one query to get a specific date, but we're using fiscal month, like starts on 10-27-2018 and ends on 11-26-2018.

Need to Month changes in query but days stay the same each time.

```
WHERE CAST(trans.createdAt as DATE) BETWEEN '2018-09-26' AND '2018-10-25'
```

How can i do this?

Any help will be thankful

Comment: Please add sample input and output data to your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: What does "days stay the same mean"? or "need to month changes"? And example might help make sense of this.

Comment: @danblack sorry for delay, example: we're in november, so need to use fiscal month that starts on 26 of later month until 25 of this month.       WHERE CAST(trans.createdAt as DATE) BETWEEN '2018-10-26' AND '2018-11-25'